# ASP.Net 6 password policy not being used from scaffolded Register.cshtml[.cs]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've configured custom values in startup for my site as follows:

```
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
```

});

I've also added a custom password validator. Neither the built in validator nor my custom one are being called though. It looks like this is because I am using a scaffolded Register.cshtml, as it works as expected on a test site without the scaffolding.

I've been able to work around it by adding the following in OnPostAsync in the scaffolded RegisterModel before the ModelState.IsValid check, but I assume there's a correct way of doing this?

```
        foreach(var pval in _userManager.PasswordValidators) {
            var result = await pval.ValidateAsync(_userManager, tuser, Input.Password);
            if (!result.Succeeded) result.Errors.ToList().ForEach(x => ModelState.AddModelError("", x.Description));
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use custom validator?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference in this step.
1.Create .net6MVC with individual account
[image]
2.Update-database
3.Add-scalffod "account\register, choose built-in context
[image]
4.Add the options configuration to program.cs
`options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;`

Then open register page.If I input a password length less then 12. The policy take effect.
[image]